# ADB over bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, adb

Is it possible to connect to ADB over bluetooth?

I am trying to test 3G data download, but want to have ability to connect to ADB without using USB. Using WiFi (local only) and 3G, as understand, will not work because Android will still use WiFi for downloads (even that WiFi is local only, no outside exit).

How can I set up connection to ADB over bluetooth to send ADB commands for Android device to execute?

Comment: That may be tricky, but you could probably do it by putting ADB in TCP mode while running a local process on the device which proxied between bluetooth and the TCP ADB service.  You might want to consider building diagnostic commands into the app itself to avoid the dependence on ADB for your field testing.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen people post that they have been able to do it just like with WiFi using Bluetooth tethering. You'll need to find your IP address.